# UI API called on a background thread error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a function that gets the context for storing to Core Data. I have it for a few view controllers, however I am getting an error.

```
private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate       
    return appDelegate.weatherPersistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

However I get an error about accessing UI API being called from a background thread.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How would I go about getting this without getting the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you see from the error, you can't call `UIApplication.shared` from a background thread. Since you don't want to have to wrap every call to our `getContext` method in `DispatchQueue.main.async`, you can update your `getContext` method to do the necessary wrapping as needed:

```
private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate
    if Thread.current.isMainThread {
        appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    } else {
        appDelegate = DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        }
    }
    return appDelegate.weatherPersistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

This code ensures that `UIApplication.shared` is only called on the main queue, even if `getContext` is called from a background thread. The nice part is that the result is returned on the original thread.